# Algorithm for inserting words in matrix

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matrix

I have words array (island, dog, cat, news for example) and empty matrix 4x4.
How I can to insert the words into a matrix and words may be arcuate?

Example for result: 
[image]

What algorithm I can use for this?

I try do it in js, but don't have idea.

```
var wordPazzle = {
    words : ['island', 'dog', 'cat', 'news'],
    generateMatrix : function() {
        //apply algorithm this
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I see  [Lee algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_algorithm), but don't know how to apply it for my function.

Comment: What is "snake style"? If you mean "the last letter of one word is adjacent to the first letter of the next one", your example doesn't show that - there's no way to get from the T in "cat" to the D in "dog".

Comment: You have to decide whether `wordPazzle` is a constructor or a plain object, because right now, it is not valid js.

Comment: what are the constraints?

Comment: Sorry, edited wordPazzle. Kevin, I mean what words can be not inline only and can looks like in image.

Comment: do you need to build any valid matrix? I suppose you want them to be mixed properly.

Comment: Does it need to be a 2d array or do you also accept 1d array ?

Comment: Herokiller Yes. But it is necessary that all the words have got into the matrix. And avoid the case when 3 words are inserted for the 4th and no space (see link with image http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2nvbecy&s=8#.VGS0BfmsVig)

Comment: aduch, all the same.

Answer (score 0):

With the following path, I get a valid matrix :

```
1   2   3   4
8   7   6   5
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
```

The implementation of this path is pretty simple.

```
function generateMatrix(length, height, words){
    wordConcatenated = words.join("");
    matrix=[]
    count = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y++){
        matrix[y] = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < length; x++){
            if (y%2){
                index = length - 1 - x;
            } else {
                index = x;
            }
            matrix[y][index] = wordConcatenated[count];
            count++;
        }
    }

    console.log(matrix)
}

generateMatrix(4,4, ['island', 'dog', 'cat', 'news']);
```

Comment: This is not the path OP asked for

Comment: Yes, path may be random and for example "CAT" can be inserting in 16 (c), 15 (a), 11 (t)

Comment: But you are looking for a valid matrix no ? Or you want to generate all valid matrices ?

Comment: I want to generate matrix with random path for all words.

Answer (score 0):

so, if you need **any** valid matrix then just choose any valid direction( for example

1 2 3 4

8 7 6 5

9 10 11 12

16 15 14 13

```
var wordPazzle = {
    words : ['island', 'dog', 'cat', 'news'],
    generateMatrix : function() {
        var a = [];
        for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
            a[i] = [];
        var w = this.words, i0 = 0, j0 = 0;
        for ( var i = 0; i < w.length; i++ ) {
            for ( var j = 0; j < w[i].length; j++ ) {
                a[i0][j0] = w[i][j];

               if (i0%2 == 0 ) {
                   if (j0 < 3 ) 
                       j0++;
                   else 
                       i0++;
               } else {
                   if (j0 > 0)
                       j0--;
                   else
                      i0++;
               }
            }
        }
        console.log(a);
        return a;
   }
};
```

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. Matrix can be invalid.